# domain name in default maven package

Tags: java, maven

When I create a Maven project using the quickstart archetype, it populates my src/main/java directory with a default package, "com.domain.my.project_name"

Is there anything that expects me to use this?  Will I cause problems by not naming my packages "com.domain.my.project_name.package_name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your project grows enough to be usefull outside of your personal use you may want to publish it to Maven Central, where groupId is required to be unique. Domain name is good in asserting uniqueness. The same applies to Java package names - as soon as they land in classpaths of other people's projects, uniquely naming them is just polite - as is putting them into artifacts with matching groupIds.

If this doesn't seem to apply to your code - you will encounter no problems. But if your project grows and gets opensourced you will face branding issues. Just look at all the confusion caused by org.apache.commons vs commons-io.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: no. Naming packages like domains is a convention. Nothing forces you to comply to that. Speaking of the Maven archetype: In most archetypes it’s just an example to get you started. If you are unsure about deleting it, use the *safely delete* action that any good IDE (IntelliJ, NetBeans, eclipse) provides.